# Create Protege Readable Ontology from .NET

Tags: c#, linq-to-xml, ontology

I am trying to create a protégé readable ontology from .NET.

I started with a 4GB .nt file and parsed out the needed classes and instances that I wish to use.  Those are stored in memory since I got it down to less than 1 minute and roughly 1GB.  They are in the form of `Dictionary<String,HashSet<String>>` right now.  The next step is to take that data and move it into an OWL Ontology.  Is there anywhere to start with how to manually loop through and do this?  All of my research points me to using Manchester OWL, but everything I can find is for use with existing tools that don't fit my needs.  I am looking for just doing a simple loop probably with LINQ to XML and I am unsure of how to format that or where to look to find how to do this.

Thanks
Jimmy

Comment: You can use the schema webpage for the definition.  I can help : http://www.w3.org/TR/owl2-xml-serialization/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can start with this

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.Linq;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string definition =
                "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\"?>" +
                "<Ontology xmlns:xsi=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance\"" +
                    " xsi:schemaLocation=\"http://www.w3.org/2002/07/owl# http://www.w3.org/2009/09/owl2-xml.xsd\"" +
                    " xmlns=\"http://www.w3.org/2002/07/owl#\"" +
                    " xml:base=\"http://example.com/myOntology\"" +
                    " ontologyIRI=\"http://example.com/myOntology\">" +
                "</Ontology>";

            XDocument doc = XDocument.Parse(definition);
            XElement ontology = (XElement)doc.FirstNode;
            XNamespace ns = ontology.Name.Namespace;

            ontology.Add(new XElement[] {
                new XElement(ns + "Prefix", new XAttribute[] {
                       new XAttribute("name", "myOnt"),
                       new XAttribute("IRI", "http://example.com/myOntology#")
                }),
                new XElement(ns + "Import", "http://example.com/someOtherOntology")
            });

        }
    }
}
​
```

Comment: This got me on the right track.  Turns out it was too big for protege to handle at least on a 16 gig machine so we parsed it differently.  Thanks for the help.

Comment: @Jimmy how did you end up parsing that?